# django memcached - is it possible to cache user forever and refresh it when user obj changes?

Tags: python, django

django memcached - is it possible to cache user forever and refresh it when user obj changes ? If yes, how ? Just provide me link for that.

That means, let us assumed, we are retreving an obj, we get cached one now and whenever we fetch, we should get cached one forever till the object is changed. Whenever its changed, automatically, cache should update its content with new data. and whenever, we fetch, it should show cached version.

One idea i have for this is, store modified user id in some memory or redis kind of fast database. We write a decorator that checks if request id is in the list of modified userids. If available, then it will be fetched from database and that key is deleted from list of modified userids. If not available, it will simple show from cache. But not sure, how to dot this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django Cache Machine https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine.

It uses 'flush list' to mark cached queries an object belongs to . When your object is saved or deleted, the flush list will be deleted. Best of all, it is easy to use.